# Does the differential operator in the heat equation have a name?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

Does the operator

$$\frac {\partial}{\partial t} - k\nabla^2$$

have a name?

Comment: I have heard it called the *heat operator*. Shocking, I know... (Certainly the $\square=c^2\partial_t^2-\nabla^2$ is called the wave operator.)

Comment: That seems like a fine name.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: Nvm.  I [found](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PDETerminology.aspx) [one](http://home.ku.edu.tr/~vkalantarov/math551/m551%28heq%29.pdf).  Thanks @Chappers.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22heat+operator%22 Literally thousands...